# Make js and css work with Ratchet's push.js

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, phonegap-build, ratchet

I'm using Ratchet to build a phonegap app. I have a tab bar at the bottom and tapping icons will take users to specific view.

My setup is basically like this: 1.html, 1.js, 1.css and 2.html, 2.js, 2.css
and I'm using Ratchet's push.js to switch between the two html.

The problem is with push.js, any scripts/css is not loaded. So if I switch to 2.html from 1.html, 2.js, 2.css are not loaded. Also, I guess cordova.js also needs to be loaded every time.

Is there a work around? Googling got me to

```
window.addEventListener('push' function(){});
```

and this might work with js but not css?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Push.js is going to load 2.html dynamically with ajax. Any javascript or styles that you want from page to should be loaded in page 1.html. Upon navigation, Push.js will parse out the content in 2.html and swap those content areas with what was on 1.html. Your javascript and css in 2.html wont be applied.

You can add an event handler to the push event as you have found, and people wired into that to load javascript when a page is loaded. Its a hack that, to me, means there is probably a better approach.

Answer (score 0):

I know this has been answered. However, I just made a change for Ratchet.js to make individual js works for each page. Please check out: https://github.com/mazong1123/ratchet-pro

What you need to do is:
1. Specify data-page attribute in your html:

```
<body>
    <div class="content" data-page="index">
    Put page content here.
    </div>
    <script src="scripts/app-index.js"></script>
</body>
```

2. Add following standard js snippet in your js file:

```js
(function () {
    // Change the settings here if you want.
    //window.RATCHET.Class.PageManager.settings.pageEntryScriptPath = 'scripts'
    //window.RATCHET.Class.PageManager.settings.pageEntryScriptPrefix = 'app-' 

    var rachetPageManager = new window.RATCHET.Class.PageManager();
    rachetPageManager.ready(function () {
      // Put your code here.
    });
})();
```

Done. Just repeat aforementioned steps for each page. You'll get script executed each time page changed.

Note: This just works for js. For css, unfortunately, you have to merge all css files into one, and refer it in your entry page.